# Assigning NSNotFound to a property?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Can I assign 'NSNotFound' to a property of type NSInteger? So here is what I have:

```
@interfcae MyClass()
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger sectionNumber;
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (id)init
{
   [my_switch isOn] ? self.sectionNumber = 0 : self.sectionNumber = NSNotFound;
}
@end
```

This throws an error saying `"Assignment to readonly property"`. Even if I just try `"self.sectionNumber = NSNotFound"`, I get the same error.

Can I not assign NSNotFound to a property? If not what could be the other options I have?

Comment: Is that your entire code? It isn't a well formed `init` method (call to super, return self). You can assign an `NSInteger` variable to `NSNotFound`.

Comment: You have not proved that `sectionNumber` is not read-only. In any case, that is not how to write an `init` method. And it's not a good use of the tripartite operator either.

Comment: I have the [super init] inside my init... Just missed adding it here since I was focusing more on NSNotFound issue.

Comment: However I did notice one thing... my header file has this property as 'readonly' and I make it 'readwrite' in my implementation file. If I remove the readonly from header and make it readwrite in my header file, it works otherwise it throws of 'Readonly property' error.

Comment: You don't make it readwrite in the .m. You need to put `readwrite` for that.

Comment: That is why I said you had not proved that it isn't read-only.

Comment: The properties are 'Readwrite' by default right?

Comment: Okay so basically you have not shown us your real code at all. Downvoted for lying to us the whole time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not showing the actual code that's causing the problem.

Comment: @tech_learning Yes, properties are read-write by default. But if you declare it `readonly` in the .h, then you must explicitly mark is `readwrite` in the .m to make it writable. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
- (id)init {
   self.sectionNumber = [my_switch isOn] ? 0 : NSNotFound;
}
```

And Wain makes a good point about this `init` method. Either rename this to something other than `init` or make this a proper `init` method.

Update:

Based on your comment you have the following in the .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger sectionNumber;
```

This means in the .m you need:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger sectionNumber;
```

Comment: Still a bad `init` though.

Comment: @matt Yeah, I just made a note of that.

Comment: I have proper init in my copy. However can I not have the property as readonly when I assign NSNotFound to it?

Comment: Making a note is not the same as showing correct code. Don't show a bad `init`.

Comment: @tech_learning See my updated answer to fix the read-only issue.

Comment: Yes I have the property as 'readonly' in header and 'readwrite' in my implementation file... same as your updated code.

Comment: @tech_learning So you are saying that it truly is marked as `readwrite` in the .m yet you still get the warning? If this is the case then why didn't you make this clear in your original question? You are wasting everyone's time here.

Comment: My intention was not to hide the code. Obviously I don't get anything by hiding from you guys if the property is readonly. I was myself trying to figure out where I am going wrong. But anyways, your answer works great. Thanks for replying!!